# How can I use an outer query variable in a nested sub query using update?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

```
update fee_schedule fs set fs.branch_id=
(
SELECT  branch_id  FROM   (SELECT  branch_id
                                       ,updated_ts
                                       ,gr_number
                                      ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY gr_number ORDER BY updated_ts desc) AS sno
                                FROM   admission_log ) x
                       WHERE  x.gr_number = fs.gr_number and to_char(x.updated_ts,'yyyymm') < fs.schedule_month
                       and rownum=1
                       order by sno
)
where fs.branch_id is null ;
```

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

The same thing I tried using:

```
update fee_schedule fs set fs.branch_id=
(
select c.branch_id
      from (select b.branch_id,updated_ts,
                   row_number() over(PARTITION by b.gr_number order by b.updated_ts desc) as Sno
                   from admission_log b
                   where b.gr_number = fs.gr_number and to_char(b.updated_ts,'yyyymm') <  fs.schedule_month ) c
      where c.sno = 1
)
where fs.branch_id is null ;
```

And I found this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "FS"."SCHEDULE_MONTH": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `keep`:

```
update fee_schedule fs
    set fs.branch_id =
            (select max(b.branch_id) keep (dense_rank first order by updated_ts desc)
              from admission_log al
                   where al.gr_number = fs.gr_number and
                         to_char(al.updated_ts, 'yyyymm') < fs.schedule_month 
            )
where fs.branch_id is null ;
```

This structure is equivalent to a "first()" aggregation function and is handy to get around Oracle's scoping limit on correlated subqueries.

Comment: simply you are amazing and on next level of understanding, can u please explain why u use max(branch_id) with keep and dense_rank ?

Comment: @abdulraheemdev . . . That part of the expression simply handles cases where there are ties.  In this case `max()` and `min()` would presumably return the same thing.